# force R to always display package name in error message

Tags: r, error-handling, package

I sometimes load multiple packages that export functions of the same name. For example, both Hmisc and dplyr have a `summarize` function, and I sometimes load both packages. I then call `summarize`, thinking that I am calling `dplyr::summarize` when I am really calling `Hmisc::summarize`. When that happens, I get an error message like this:

```
Error in summarize(., mean = mean(instRating)) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default
```

The message is initially hard to understand, because my code contains no errors. It takes me a minute to realize that I've called a function in the wrong package. The error message would be easier to understand if its first line included the name of the relevant package:

```
Error in Hmisc::summarize(., mean = mean(instRating)) :
```

Is there a way to force R to display the package name in these error messages?

I know that I can get around the problem by typing out `dplyr::summarize` or by changing the order in which I load packages. But my interest lies with adding detail to R's error messages.

Comment: not the answer, but perhaps useful:: `environmentName( environment( summarise ) )`

Comment: Based on my understanding of how namespace lookup and the creation of these automated error messages works, I'd say there isn't (unless you are open to wrapping every command in a `tryCatch`). But I've been surprised before. Your best bet would probably be managing your `conflicts.policy` as described in `help("library")`.

Comment: _Potentially_ useful blog post: [Managing Search Path Conflicts](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/03/19/managing-search-path-conflicts/) (anyway, it's a nice post)

Comment: @Henrik, thank you. That is a good post. It takes up the `conflicts.policy` that @Roland mentions. It also made me aware of a relatively new argument to `library()`, `exclude`, which lets users exclude certain functions that would ordinarily be attached by `library()`. For example, `library(MASS, exclude = "select")` allows one to exclude `MASS::select()` while still loading the other exported MASS functions.

Comment: I found some partial luck using `sys.calls()`, but unfortunately it appears the magrittr pipe operator `%>%` is sometimes seen in an anonymous/temporary (unnamed) environment, and while it is feasible to bake in a special case with `%>%`, there are other inline operators that likely do the same thing ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the documentation of the base option `error`:

> 'error': either a function or an expression governing the handling
>            of non-catastrophic errors such as those generated by 'stop'
>            as well as by signals and internally detected errors.  If the
>            option is a function, a call to that function, with no
>            arguments, is generated as the expression.  By default the
>            option is not set: see 'stop' for the behaviour in that case.
>            The functions 'dump.frames' and 'recover' provide
>            alternatives that allow post-mortem debugging.  Note that
>            these need to specified as e.g. 'options(error =
>            utils::recover)' in startup files such as '.Rprofile'.

So it should be possible to define a function that returns the name of the package where the function that’s throwing the error lives. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
data(mtcars)

print_package <- function() {
    calls <- sys.calls()
    call <- calls[[length(calls) - 1]]
    fun.name <- as.character(call)[1]
    pkg.name <- sub("package:", "", getAnywhere(fun.name)$where[1], fixed = TRUE)
    message (paste0("In ", pkg.name))
}

options(error = print_package)

summarize(mtcars$mpg)
```

Returns:

```
Error in summarize(mtcars$mpg) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default
In Hmisc
```

## Edit (using `rlang::trace_back`)

It turns out that there is a much cleaner way of doing this (credit goes to Hadley Wickham and his "Advanced R, Second edition"):

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
data(mtcars)

print_trace_back <- function() {
    print(rlang::trace_back(bottom = sys.frame(-1)))
}

options(error = print_trace_back)
```

Seems to handle errors gracefully:

```
> summarize(mtcars$mpg)
Error in summarize(mtcars$mpg) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default
    █
 1. └─Hmisc::summarize(mtcars$mpg)
>
> Hmisc::summarize(mtcars$mpg)
Error in Hmisc::summarize(mtcars$mpg) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default
    █
 1. └─Hmisc::summarize(mtcars$mpg)
>
> summarize(mtcars$mpg, as.character(mtcars$apa), mean)
Error in tapply(X, INDEX, FUN, ..., simplify = simplify) : 
  arguments must have same length
    █
 1. └─Hmisc::summarize(mtcars$mpg, as.character(mtcars$apa), mean)
 2.   └─Hmisc::mApply(X, byc, FUN, ..., keepmatrix = nc > 1)
 3.     └─base::tapply(X, INDEX, FUN, ..., simplify = simplify)
 4.       └─base::stop("arguments must have same length")
>
> (function() stop("Error"))()
Error in (function() stop("Error"))() : Error
    █
 1. └─(function() stop("Error"))()
 2.   └─base::stop("Error")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well (for me) when the function is called in the `pkg::function` format (though that specific pattern clearly shows which package). I wonder if other methods (anon functions?) would also show this anonymity.

Comment: @r2evans can you come with a specific example where it fails drastically? It seems replacing `'fun.name` in `getAnywhere` with `gsub('(.*)?:', '', fun.name)` returns the expected result in those situations.

Comment: I *had* found something that didn't find the package correctly, but I cannot remember and cannot come up with likely candidates. I'll come back if I do, sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `conflict_prefer("summarize", "dplyr")` from **conflicted** package by Hadley Wickham.  One drawback is that you need to identify winner for every conflict.